# MVC.net Hiding Fields within a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, http, asp.net-web-api

So I am creating a an API with ASP.net MVC Web API. I currently have a model which contains the fields for a user in the database. I have a password field on this model. See below for an example.

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set;  }
 }
```

I return this model using JSON when a controller method is called over HTTP. This works fine. 
My question is, how do I stop the password field being returned alongside with it? Without removing the field altogether.

My initial idea is to create another model class which I use to return the data without the password field, but I'd rather not repeat myself for the sake of one field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.  You should replace that with a hash.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks. I neglated to mention that the password is hashed and salted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to mark these fields with

```
 [JsonIgnore]
 [XmlIgnore]
 public string Password { get; set;  }
```

Preventing these fields to be used in either JSON or XML requests.

Comment: Absolute star. This did the job.